Definite Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(1+x+y)^{5/2}} \mathrm{d} x$
My Attempt
The integral I'm trying to solve is
\begin{align*}
    I_1 &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(1+x+y)^{5/2}} \mathrm{d} x.
\end{align*}
Letting $u=\frac{1}{(1+x+y)^{3/2}}$, we have
\begin{align*}
    I_1 &= \frac{2}{3} \int_{0}^{(1+y)^{-3/2}} \log \left( \frac{1-u^{2/3}(1+y)}{u^{2/3}} \right) \mathrm{d} u\\
    &= \frac{2}{3} \int_{0}^{(1+y)^{-3/2}} \log \left[ \frac{(1+u^{1/3}\sqrt{1+y})(1-u^{1/3}\sqrt{1+y})}{u^{2/3}} \right] \mathrm{d} u\\
    &= \frac{2}{3} \biggl[ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{(1+y)^{-3/2}} \log(1+u^{1/3}\sqrt{1+y}) \mathrm{d} u}_{I_2} \, + \, \underbrace{\int_{0}^{(1+y)^{-3/2}} \log(1-u^{1/3}\sqrt{1+y}) \mathrm{d} u}_{I_3} \biggr.\\
    &\qquad \biggl. - \, \frac{2}{3} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{(1+y)^{-3/2}} \log(u) \mathrm{d} u}_{I_4} \biggr].  
\end{align*}
I have found that
\begin{align*}
    I_2 &= (1+y)^{3/2} \log(2+y) - \frac{1}{(1+y)^2} \left[ \frac{1}{3} (y+2)^3 - \frac{3}{2} (y+2)^2 + 3(y+2) - \log(y+2) - \frac{11}{6} \right]
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    I_4 &= (1+y)^{3/2} \left[ \frac{3}{2} \log(1+y) - 1 \right].
\end{align*}
The following is my attempt at solving $I_3$. Letting $v=1-u^{1/3}\sqrt{1+y}$, we have
\begin{align}
    \nonumber I_3 &= \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \int_{-y}^{1} 3(v-1)^2 \log(v) \mathrm{d} v\\
    \nonumber &= \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \left\{ \left[ \log(v) \left( v^3-3v^2+3v \right) \right]_{-y}^{1} - \int_{-y}^{1} \left( v^3 -3v^2 + 3v \right) \cdot \frac{1}{v} \mathrm{d} v \right\}\\
    \nonumber &= \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \left\{ \left[ 0-\log(-y) \left( -y^3-3y^2-3y \right) \right] - \int_{-y}^{1} \left( v^2-3v+3 \right) \mathrm{d} v \right\}\\
    \nonumber &= \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \left\{ -\log(-y) \left( -y^3-3y^2-3y \right) - \left[ \frac{1}{3}v^3 - \frac{3}{2} v^2 + 3v \right]_{-y}^{1} \right\}\\
    &= \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \left[ -\log(-y) \left( -y^3-3y^2-3y \right) - \frac{11}{6} - \frac{1}{3} y^3 - \frac{3}{2} y^2 - 3y \right]. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Question
Before dealing with the main integral ($I_1$), I have proved that
\begin{align*}
    \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)^{5/2}} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{4}{3} [\log(2)-1],
\end{align*}
that is $I_1$ with $y=0$. Now, I would like to prove that
\begin{align*}
    I_1 &= \frac{2\log\left(y+1\right)+4\log\left(2\right)-4}{3\left(y+1\right)^\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{align*}
In (1), I encountered a $\log(-y)$. Does this mean that I have to restrict $y$ to $y \leq 0$? How could I deal with this? Can anyone help me with this problem? I am open to any suggestions/solutions, including that for the very first integral in the question. Any help/feedback is much appreciated. Thank you!

Substitute $t= \frac x{1+y}$\begin{align*}
    &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{(1+x+y)^{5/2}} {d} x\\
   =&\ \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln (1+y)}{(1+t)^{5/2}}+ \frac{\ln t} {(1+t)^{5/2}}\ dt\\
   =&\ \frac{2\ln(1+y)+4(\ln 2-1)}{3(1+y)^{3/2}}
\end{align*}
where the first integral is simply $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+t)^{5/2}}dt=\frac23$ and the second is per your $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln t}{(1+t)^{5/2}} {d}t= \frac{4}{3} (\ln 2-1)$.

how did you guess the required substitution?

@Debu To convert $\frac1{1+x+y}$ to $\frac1{1+\frac x{1+y}}$

The simple solution I'm expecting. Thank you very much!

Define
\begin{align*}
I(a) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(a+x)^{3/2}} \mathrm{d} x\\
&\overset{x\to a\tan^2 (x)}=\frac2{\sqrt a}\int_0^{\pi/2}(\log(a)+2\ln\tan(x))\sin(x) \mathrm{d} x\\
&=\frac{2\log(4a)}{\sqrt a}.
\end{align*}
and hence
$$ I'(a)=-\frac32\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(a+x)^{5/2}} \mathrm{d} x=\frac{2-\log(4a)}{a\sqrt a}.$$
So
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(a+x)^{5/2}} \mathrm{d} x=-\frac23\frac{2-\log(4a)}{a\sqrt a}=\frac{2\log(4a)-4}{3a\sqrt a}. $$
Letting $a=1+y$ gives the desired result.

That's cool! Is this considered as Feynman's trick for solving integrals?

@KarelDwinugrohoBowosebua Yes, you are right.

Neat! I've actually tried to solve this integral with the same trick, but I failed to do so, haha... Thank you @xpaul!

You are welcome!

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\Large\tt I}_{1} & \equiv \color{#44f}{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over
\pars{1 + x + y}^{5/2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over \pars{1 + y}^{5/2}}\,\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\color{red}{\nu}\ -\ 1} \over
\bracks{\rule{0pt}{4mm}1 + x/\pars{1 + y}}^{\, 5/2}}\,\dd x\right\vert_{\nu\ =\ 1}
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
& {1 \over
\bracks{\rule{0pt}{4mm}1 + x/\pars{1 + y}}^{\, 5/2}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-5/2 \choose n}\pars{x \over
1 + y}^{n}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{n + 3/2 \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{n}}\pars{1 + y}^{-n}\,x^{n}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{{\Gamma\pars{5/2 +n} \over
\Gamma\pars{5/2}}\,
\pars{1 + y}^{-n}}\,\,{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n!}
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\Large\tt I}_{1} & \equiv \color{#44f}{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over
\pars{1 + x + y}^{5/2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & = \ {1 \over \pars{1 + y}^{\, 5/2}}\
\partiald{}{\nu}\ \overbrace{\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\nu}{\Gamma\pars{5/2 - \nu} \over
\Gamma\pars{5/2}}\pars{1 + y}^{\nu}}_{\nu\ =\ 1}}
^{\ds{Ramanujan's\ Master\ Theorem}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\color{#44f}{{2 \over 3}{\ln\pars{1 + y} + 2\ln\pars{2} - 2 \over \pars{1 + y}^{3/2}}}} \\ &
\end{align}

Wow... this is quite 'a lot' for me personally. I guess I still have a lot to study to understand this entirely. Either way, this is very interesting! Thanks for the response!

@KarelDwinugrohoBowosebua Ramanujan’s$\ldots$ is a powerful tool.

Let’s consider the parametrised integral $$
I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x+y)^{\frac{5}{2}}} d x=(1+y)^{a-\frac{5}{2}} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^{a-1}}{(1+u)^{\frac{5}{2}}} d u \stackrel{(*)}{=}  (1+y)^{a-\frac{5}{2}} B\left(a, \frac{5}{2}-a\right) 
$$
where $u=\frac{x}{1+y}.$
$$
I=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left[(1+y)^{a-\frac{5}{2}} B\left(a, \frac{5}{2}-a\right)\right]\right|_{a=1}=\frac{2[\ln (y+1)-2+2 \ln 2]}{3(y+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
For details of $(*)$, please refer to the post.

Wow... very cool! I love this answer so much, as I personally find it quite convenient to solve an integral by manipulation via a distribution, when possible. Thank you!
